# Need to omit/remove duplicate nodes in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Can any one help me out need to omit the duplicates from an XML tag using XSLT 1.0.

I'm new to XSLT and any help is really appreciated.

Input

```
<JdeVariable>
    <ns0:JDE>
        <ns0:JdeNumber>39184</ns0:JdeNumber>
    </ns0:JDE>
    <ns0:JDE>
        <ns0:JdeNumber>39184</ns0:JdeNumber>
    </ns0:JDE>
    <ns0:JDE>
        <ns0:JdeNumber>39184</ns0:JdeNumber>
    </ns0:JDE>
    <ns0:JDE>
        <ns0:JdeNumber>39186</ns0:JdeNumber>
    </ns0:JDE>
    <ns0:JDE>
        <ns0:JdeNumber>39186</ns0:JdeNumber>
    </ns0:JDE>
    <ns0:JDE>
        <ns0:JdeNumber>39186</ns0:JdeNumber>
    </ns0:JDE>
</JdeVariable>
```

Output Expected:

```
<JdeVariable>
    <ns0:JDE>
        <ns0:JdeNumber>39184</ns0:JdeNumber>
    </ns0:JDE>
    <ns0:JDE>
        <ns0:JdeNumber>39186</ns0:JdeNumber>
    </ns0:JDE>
</JdeVariable>
```

Comment: Try [Muenchian grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Muenchian+Grouping) on SO. You will find a lot of examples solving this problem.

Comment: @aniket V. can you help me out please

Answer (score 0):

Since you are stuck with XSLT 1.0, `muenchian grouping` needs to be used for eliminating the duplicate nodes.

Define a `xsl:key` using as below

```
<xsl:key name="key-val" match="ns0:JDE" use="ns0:JdeNumber" />
```

Match the template to filter only the unique nodes

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:JDE[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key-val', ns0:JdeNumber))]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The complete XSLT code is as below (refer to the comments for the approach)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="http://someurl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="key-val" match="ns0:JDE" use="ns0:JdeNumber" />

    <!-- identity transform template to copy input as is to output -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns0:JDE[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key-val', ns0:JdeNumber))]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns0:JDE" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<JdeVariable xmlns:ns0="http://someurl">
    <ns0:JDE>
        <ns0:JdeNumber>39184</ns0:JdeNumber>
    </ns0:JDE>
    <ns0:JDE>
        <ns0:JdeNumber>39186</ns0:JdeNumber>
    </ns0:JDE>
</JdeVariable>
```

Comment: HI@aniket I was able to modify the question can you please help me out. I really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance..!

Comment: I have updated the solution based on the changes to the input XML. Please ensure you use the correct namespace identified by `ns0` in your XSL.